# Ionic Label font size

Tags: ionic-framework

I have some doubts that is too much for me, but it may be nothing for you. I would like to know how to decrease the text size of the select "All Regions". I've tried it in several ways but it never decreases the text, I need it to be smaller.

my SCSS:

```
.selecthome{
    color: #179c90;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

and HTML

```
<ion-label stacked class="selecthome" padding>
  <b>
    <h6>TODAS AS REGIÕES</h6>
  </b>
</ion-label>

<ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender"  class = "setaselect" no-padding>
  <ion-option value="c">Centro</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="s">Zona Sul</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="n">Zona Norte</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="o">Zona Oeste</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of  `<h6>` tags and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<p>` `<span>` or something else instead `<h6>`.

The `<h*>` elements have `font-size` and other attributes marked with `!important`, you cannot override them.